# Совместный доступ к файлам из разных процессов

Tags: c#, c++, c++builder

Возникает ошибка открытия бинарного файла: *"файл уже открыт"*. Дело в том, что у меня есть два приложения: одно, написанное на C++Builder:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::BitBtn1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TFileStream *fileStream;

    fileStream->Free(); 

    fileStream = new TFileStream("E:/DELETE/n.dat",fmOpenReadWrite);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::StringGrid2SetEditText(TObject *Sender, int ACol,
      int ARow, const UnicodeString Value)
{
    fileStream->Position = (sizeof(nr) * nn);

    fileStream->Write(&nrt.nn, sizeof(nr));
}
```

В данном приложении вносятся изменения и сохраняются в файл. Далее я читаю в C# то что записалось:

```
private List<Int32> ReadBinaryFiles(string path)
{
    List<Int32> testL = new List<Int32>();

    Int32 obj = 0;
    try
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(
                File.Open(
                        path, 
                        FileMode.Open, 
                        FileAccess.Read, 
                        FileShare.ReadWrite)))
        {
            while (reader.PeekChar() > -1)
            {
                obj = reader.ReadInt32();

                testL.Add(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: {0}", e.Message);

        Console.ResetColor();
    }
    return testL;
}
```

Я понимаю, что вверху нужно закрыть этот файл, но мне нужно работать с файлом без его закрытия, возможно что-то придумать? Если нет, тот где правильно поставить `fileStream->Free();`, чтобы при повторной записи файл был доступен? Может возможно открыть файл с разрешением на совместный доступ на чтение?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper задача стоит, что бы работало и там и там. Но если открыт файл на С++ то С# кинет ошибку, но можно сделать например повтор опроса это уже меньше проблем я думаю, как тогда правильно открыть файл произвести запись и закрыть его ? Спасибо за отзыв

Comment: Просто интересно, а переписать все на C# или билдр не вариант?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Возможно вам нужен [fmShareDenyNone](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_fmShareDenyNone.html) (для С++) и [FileShare.ReadWrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) (для C#).

Это даст вам возможность открыть файл так чтоб другие процессы тоже могли с ним работать.

```
fileStream = new TFileStream("E:/DELETE/n.dat", fmOpenReadWrite | fmShareDenyNone);
```

> fmShareDenyNone is one of the attributes assignable in the Create. The
>   TFileStream is used to read and write files. It specifies file sharing
>   that does not prevent any other applications from reading from or
>   writing to the file.